# IBM ClearCase: removed VOB and its tag accidentally

Tags: clearcase

I have executed the following commands by clear tool:

1. cleartool unregister -vob -uuid 6ca911d.229a41bb.942b.fd:ed:f2:bb:5c:f8
2. cleartool rmtag -vob \test

May I ask is there any way to rollback those things I did?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can  [register](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_register.htm), then [mktag](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktag.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-2-2-7&lang=en) the vob again.

```
cleartool register -vob /global/path/test.vbs 
cleartool mktag -vob -tag \test -pub -password clearcase -host <clearcaseHost> -gpath /global/path/test.vbs /global/path/test.vbs
```

Comment: And may I ask will the uuid be regenerated after i register? As there already some stream/view are created from the tag, seems they are referencing the uuid 6ca911d.229a41bb.942b.fd:ed:f2:bb:5c:f8

Comment: @skaso12 the uuid should be the one already present in the test.vbs folder. It should be the same. Unchanged.